# Error getting hexadecimal color code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, rgb

I have a very big problem with HEX codes and WPF. I'm writing a simple color palette maker.

The app asks you to set a default color as color base, it converts that color into a palette and it adds every color of that palette in a ListBox. When you double-click an item, it copies the RGB code in the clipboard, but when I paste that code in a webpage or in google, the result is completely different.

This is the code that copies the HEX code in the clipboard.

```
private void box_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ListBox list = sender as ListBox;
    ListBoxItem item = list.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(item.Background.ToString());
}
```

Can you Help me? Thanks.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: What do you mean _result is completely different_? Show an example, please.

Comment: It looks like at the moment you're just calling `ToString()` on a `Brush` instance, and hoping that will be what you want. I see nothing in the documentation saying that that will be a hex representation.

Comment: See following : https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/216-color-browser-safe-palette?_ga=2.74491730.1741243603.1603127672-2094438287.1603127672

Comment: @Inkling00 - If background of your item is blue than you will get `#FF0000FF` from the clipboard. Everything correct.

Comment: Post edited. Thanks for support

Comment: When I select the darkest red color, the result color is orange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two different color models. There is [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) with a channel for red, green and blue and there is also [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model#ARGB_(word-order)), which has an additional alpha channel, to specify how opaque the color is.

- ##FF0000 is the hexadecimal representation of the color red in RGB
- ##**FF**FF0000 is the hexadecimal representation of the **fully opaque** color red in ARGB

The [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color?view=netcore-3.1) structure will return a hex string in ARGB format, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.tostring?view=netcore-3.1):

> The string representation of the color. The default implementation represents the Byte values in hex form, prefixes with the # character, and **starts with the alpha channel**. For example, the ToString() value for AliceBlue is #FFF0F8FF.

You HTML color picker will misinterpret the color string, as it interprets the first 6 hex characters as RGB and ignores the rest. Consequently, the alpha channel will be used for red, red for green, green for blue and blue will be ignored. You can test this by appending arbitrary numbers or removing the first two (alpha) hex characters and the color will be correct.

You can get around this by formatting the hex string yourself. The [format specifier `X2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier) will display two characters for a hexadecimal number, even if the value can be represented by one character, e.g. `10` as `A` will be `0A`.

```
private void box_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Controls.ListBox list = sender as ListBox;
   ListBoxItem item = list.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;

   var brush = (SolidColorBrush)item.Background;
   var color = brush.Color;
   var hexColor = $"#{color.R:X2}{color.G:X2}{color.B:X2}";

   System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(hexColor);
}
```